# apex pageblocksection help text broken

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, helptext

I created a simple visualforce which has a form and an input field. I have give a help text to pageblocksection. Below is my VF page code.

```
<apex:page showheader="true" sidebar="true" name="AMP" >
<apex:includeLightning /> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">   
    <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem helpText="Enter valid install url format">
          <apex:outputLabel for="txtUserName" value="User name123" />
            <apex:panelGroup >
              <div class="requiredInput"><div class="requiredBlock"></div>
                <apex:inputtext html-placeholder="<USER NAME>"  id="txtUserName" ></apex:inputtext>
              </div>
            </apex:panelGroup>
          </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
      </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</html>
```

This help text is broken in some salesforce account but not is all...
I have one `Group Edition` account in which the helptext is broken. Below is the image

[image: Group Edition Broken helpText]

And Now I have one snap shot a developer edition with same visual force code.

[image: Dev Edition Proper helpText]